# How to hide the sections in the tableview after deleting a particular section from tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am having three sections ([see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRPmy.png)) in which one section is to display the items and remaining two cells are designed by using stroyboard now if i delete all the items using delete button in first section then the remaining two sections need to be hidden and to display some text can anyone help me how to do this ?

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 3
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if (section == 0){
        return itemsArray.count
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! productTableViewCell
        tableDetails.isHidden = false
        myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        let arr = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
        let urls = NSURL(string: arr["img"] as! String)
        let data = NSData (contentsOf: urls! as URL)
        cell.imageview.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        cell.nameLabel.text = arr["productName"]as! String
        var price = arr["productPrice"] as! String
        print(price)
        var Quantity : Float = 1
        let itemId : Int =  arr["sku"] as! Int
        print(itemId)
        for aDic in CartArray{
            if aDic["id"] == String(itemId){

                Quantity = Float(String(aDic["quantity"]!))!
            }
        }
        print(CartArray)
        cell.stepper.value = Double(Int(Quantity))
        cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChange(stepper:)), for:.valueChanged)
        price = price.replacingOccurrences(of: "KD", with: "")
        cartstring = String(Float(price)! * Quantity) + "0KD"
        cell.priceLabel.text = cartstring
        let quantityText = String(Quantity)
        let endIndex = quantityText.index(quantityText.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
        let truncated = quantityText.substring(to: endIndex)
        cell.quantityTextField.text = truncated
        cell.price = price
        cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteButtonAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }else if indexPath.section == 1{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "couponcell", for: indexPath) as! CouponTableViewCell
        cell.applyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(applyButtonAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checkout", for: indexPath) as! checkoutTableViewCell
        cell.finalCartpriceLabel.text = total
        return cell
    }
}
func deleteButtonAction(button : UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        self.itemsArray.remove(at: (index?.row)!)
        self.tableDetails.deleteRows(at: [index!], with: .automatic)
        tableDetails.reloadData()
     }
```

Comment: do you want show new label titled: "No Data Found/ List is empty"? is that your requirement?

Comment: "you shopping cart is empty" like this text and the remaining two sections needs to be hided @LalKrishna

Comment: just create new `UIView` with centralised title & unhide it when `self.itemsArray` is empty

Comment: how to check that condition and where i need to check that condition ?

Comment: unhide the view on `numberOfRows(inSection:)`  delegate method.

Comment: can u explain clearly i was new to swift

Comment: Add a condition in `numberOfSections`: the simplest form is `return <dataArrayOfSection0>.isEmpty ? 1 : 3`

Comment: i didn't understand clearly @vadian ?

Comment: No offense but if you don't understand this read the basics about table views.

Comment: see my answer below @Thiru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked for me perfectly

```
func deleteButtonAction(button : UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        self.itemsArray.remove(at: (index?.row)!)
        self.tableDetails.deleteRows(at: [index!], with: .automatic)
        tableDetails.reloadData()
        if (tableView(tableDetails, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) == 0){
            tableDetails.isHidden = true
        }
        if (tableDetails.isHidden == true){
            self.loadingLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
            self.loadingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            self.loadingLabel.text = "Your shopping cart is empty"
            self.loadingLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 320, width: 140, height: 30)
            view.addSubview(loadingLabel)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for `self.itemsArray.count > 0` inside your `func numberOfSections(in:)` and show all the three sections for this condition. Otherwise, return only the first section and this will automatically hide the other two.

**Example:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if self.itemsArray.count > 0 {
        return 3
    }
    return 1
}
```

Comment: i need to replace this function instead of my rows in section ?

Comment: No, modify the `numberOfSections(in:)` method's body

Comment: not this i am having three sections in which first section i will load the data and 9 items in my array will be loaded and remaining sections i have designed in storyboard as shown in image i am having a button in my first section cells that if i delete all the items in the cart then only the table view needs to hide and display some label text @nayeem

Comment: Your requirements are confusing. In your question you said ___if i delete all the items using delete button in first section then the remaining two sections need to be hidden___ and now you are saying the opposite!!

Comment: i explained that only just see my image i need to delete all items using delete button then if all the items got deleted from section 1 then the remaining sections are there that is coupon code section and checkout section needs to be hide after deleting all items from cart and should display some text on hide screen

Comment: dynamically it need to hide after deleting all items from cart

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `numberOfSections` with:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if self.itemsArray.count > 0 {
        return 3
    }
    //Show Message List is Empty
    return 1
}
```

Comment: not this i am having three sections in which first section i will load the data and 9 items in my array will be loaded and in remaining sections i have designed in storyboard as shown in image i am having a delete button in my first section that if i delete all the items in the cart then only the table view needs to hide and display some label text @Lal Krishna

Answer (score 0):

You can manage something like,

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
if (section == 0){
    return itemsArray.count
}else{


    if self.itemsArray.count == 0 {
    return 0
   }
   else{
        return 1
     }
}

 }
```

Comment: i need to display some text in place of uitableview after hiding can u explain how ?

Comment: you can add one label in your main view in your initial setup and you can show and hide that label conditionally ! You need to learn basic. Read some good tutorials and article! because this is very basic concepts that you are asking!

Comment: i was asking that i am having section 1 with different items but if i delete all the items after running application then only the remaining sections need to hide and display some text

Answer (score 0):

in numberOfSection datasource methods, check if itemArray has no elements, return just one section. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, check the same condition again, and show the empty text in this.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if(itemArray.count > 0)
    {
      if (section == 0){
        return itemsArray.count
      }else{
        return 1
      }
    } else {
       return 1;
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(itemArray.count > 0)
    {
    }else {
       //Show empty text view
    }
}
```

Comment: not like this i am having three sections in which first section i will load the data and 9 items in my array will be loaded and in remaining i have designed in storyboard as shown in image i am having a button in my first section that if i delete all the items in the cart then only the table view needs to hide and display some label text  @Vikas Mishra